# How can I center a line of text?

Tags: support, mathjax

How can I put the following on it's own, *centered* line:
$\bar{f}(a) = f(a)$ for all $a \in A$ 
because right now it's left aligned?

Answer (score 12):

Use double $$ signs rather than single $ signs to center a line of TeX.

$$\bar{f}(a) = f(a) \  \forall a \in A$$
$$\text{or}$$
$$\bar{f}(a) = f(a) \text{ for all } a \in A$$
$$\mbox{or}$$
$$\mbox{$\bar{f}(a) = f(a)$ for all $a \in A$}$$

```
$$\bar{f}(a) = f(a) \  \forall a \in A$$
$$\text{or}$$
$$\bar{f}(a) = f(a) \text{ for all } a \in A$$
$$\mbox{or}$$
$$\mbox{$\bar{f}(a) = f(a)$ for all $a \in A$}$$
```

Comment: but what if I want it to have a mix of math and text, as in my example?

Comment: You can use \text{insert text here} within TeX lines. Note that your "for all" is a common math symbol and its LaTeX code is \forall.

Comment: If you wish to use multi lines in a single `$$` environment you can use `\\ ` as a linebreak.